# XML File as repository

Tags: xml, file, parsing

I am developing a WPF application using FW 4.0 for which I need to save the application data i.e. (Setting) in a xml file.

I have used 2.0 earlier I was wondering what is the best approach to create xml file and then able to modify (append, add new element and delete) in the xml file. The XML file will have many Elements and child elements.

Can some one point me to a link/suggest approach for creating a generic method which could be called for add/modify/delete the Element.

Answer (score 1):

I find [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) one of the most convenient and clear way to handle XML in .NET 4.0 (and it's also available in .NET 3.5).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend you creating a class to represent your settings and then use XML serialization for saving and retrieving them.

Handling it as raw XML isn't recommendable, you're likely to end up with ugly code, difficult to maintain.

A quick start tutorial on the subject of XML serialization in C#: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

If you have your reasons to go with raw XML, however, then LINQ to XML recommended by Petr Abdulin is a good choice.

As a side note - LINQ to XML is only recommendable for small or medium-sized XML files (thereby suitable for purposes of storing application settings), but it should not be used for handling big files. LINQ to XML reads in and parses XML files in their entirety. If they're large, it's better to use an `XmlReader` and process them sequentially.

Comment: Morawski thanks for your response. The link you provided was verymuch useful as a startup, well my app requirement is - it should be able to manage web.config file. Let's say asp.net web.config setting (i.e.) The app should create intially the config file(which already available in asp.net) for the first time and later on it should be able to append tags under appsetting or anyother tag. Well I was looking for some link\sample which could help although I have sample console which writes into the config file but appending\deleting is what I am looking for right now.

Comment: @user1634843 if you update your question by posting sample XML and sample outcomes (the result you'd like see), I'll post code demonstrating how to achieve this via LINQ to XML

Comment: Hi Konrad, As new to stackoverflow and not sure if I can put all the code here, alternative I have put my query and concern at http://vbcity.com/forums/p/166424/711062.aspx#711062 I would appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: Below is the sample XML for which class are to be desinged. Which I did but the serialization is not as expected.                                                  <TDSource ID="1"> <Name>AJ</Name> <TDRules> <TDRule ID="1" Nmae="Rule1"> <TDRule ID="2" Nmae="Rule2"> </TDRules> </TDSource>